# lightning-record-edit-form: Not Refreshing - Caching Issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

**Problem** - I have a DataTable with a Modify action that shows a *lightning-record-edit-form* when clicked.  The user updates the *lightning-record-edit-form* and clicks the Submit button.  The data is successfully modified behind the scenes, but the old values remain in the *lightning-record-edit-form* the next time I show it, unless I refresh the entire page.  Is there a way to force a *lightning-record-edit-form* to refresh its data?

**Markup**

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case__c"
    onsuccess={DetailSuccess} record-id={DetailRecordId}
    onsubmit={RecordSubmit} if:true={FormVisible}>
```

**Scenario**

{record-id} is set to X, X is updated, and then {record-id} is set to Y.  Then I set the {record-id} back to X, but the old values of X appear instead of the modified values, until I refresh the entire page in the browser.

Comment: when you change X to Y, are the values changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not because of cache. Initially (before changing values) when you change `record-id` the values in all `input-field`s will also reflect correct record values but when you change any of the inputs, it becomes `dirty` and will no longer reflect the values according to the changes in form (record-id) and to get the changes appropriately reflect the changes in record-id, you should use `reset()` method on inputs.

```
refreshValues() {
    const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
    if (inputFields) {
        inputFields.forEach((field) => {
            field.reset();
        });
    }
}
```

Invoke `refreshValues()` whenever you want to refresh the form - especially when you are changing record-id.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately, this doesn't do the trick.  Did you test this?

Comment: yes i tested it, it will work and I cannot create it in playground, so can you post full code in question?

Comment: Don't think I can, its too large and too sensitive.  I posted another question that may help shine some light on what I'm asking (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278091/dirty-object-refresh-from-server).