# Dirty Object - Refresh From Server

Tags: lightning-web-components

**Context -** I am using an LWC Datatable to visualize data, which has a 'Modify' action that loads the row into a lightning-record-edit-form dynamically (when clicked).  After modifying the data, saving it and then clicking modify again, the lightning-record-edit-form shows the old values (like a dirty flag is not being respected).

**Question -** How do I get the new version of a record without refreshing the page in LWC?

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case"
  record-id={DynamicallyLoadedId}>
```

In the above edit form, I am loading a Case record via swapping out the *DynamicallyLoadedId*.  When I load the record a second, third, fourth time, the original page load values remain.  I want to get the newly saved version of the Case object, without refreshing the entire page.

Comment: This service uses the same cache as the uiRecordApi getRecord service. If you use an (at)track property with the getRecord wire, you can use refreshApex in your onsuccess handler of the form to force refresh of that cache. Check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex for some info on "refreshing the cache".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing custom Apex and stripping out the submit button.